# join two tables and view columns using date

Tags: mysql

I have two tables want two joining using date but query has error

```
CREATE TABLE `reg_data3` (
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `time` time NOT NULL,
  `rainfall` float default NULL,
  `evep` float default NULL,
  `max_temp` float default NULL,
  `min_temp` float default NULL,
  `sunshine_hrs` float default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`date`)
) 
ENGINE=MyISAM 
DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `velocity` (
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `run` float NOT NULL,
  `velocity` float NOT NULL
)
ENGINE=MyISAM 
DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

query is

```
SELECT 
  A.date, 
  A.rainfall, 
  A.evep, 
  A.max_temp, 
  A.min_temp, 
  A.sunshine_hrs, 
  B.run, 
  B.velocity 
FROM 
  reg_data3 A 
  INNER JOIN velocity B 
    ON A.date = B.date 
WHERE 
  year(DATE_FORMAT(date, '%y-%m-%d'))='2008' AND
  month(DATE_FORMAT(date, '%y-%m-%d'))='04'
ORDER BY 
  A.date ;`
```

Display error = `column 'date' in where clause is ambiguous`

Comment: yeah, you forgot the aliases !!

Comment: The error is self explanatory _Display error = column 'date' in where clause is ambiguous_.  Ambiguous/ not clear.  Put the table alias in front of the field here: `WHERE year(DATE_FORMAT(date, '%y-%m-%d'))='2008'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's your

```
DATE_FORMAT(date, '%y-%m-%d')
```

parts in the WHERE statement, you need to quantify the date column (either A. or B.), like you have everywhere else